# Accessing alfresco document from Window application

Tags: java, alfresco

I set up Alfresco on Linux Server.I want to access the documents and content of Alfresco from my Window Application. How can i access it and can it be OK? And Also which way is the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alfresco provides several APIs to access your content. In your case you need a remote API that can access Alfresco from the Windows machine. The Alfresco Java Foundation API is a Java API that can only be used on the Alfresco Repository Machine (same Java VM).

You could either use the [REST API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/HTTP_API) or the [CMIS standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_Management_Interoperability_Services) (which I would suggest).

If you are developing the Client in Java you can use the [OpenCMIS client library](http://incubator.apache.org/chemistry/opencmis.html) for example to access Alfresco. There are probably also CMIS clients libraries for other languages.

You should evaluate if CMIS has all the capabilities you need, because since it is a common standard it does not support the complete feature set of Alfresco.

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco provides developer tools for interacting with an Alfresco repository. You can consult the [developer documentation](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Developer_Guide) for more information on this.

For use in Java, Alfresco provides the [Alfresco Java Foundation API](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Java_Foundation_API) that should be able to help you.